# Getting java enum by name

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to get an enum by searching on its name instead of value ? For example :

```
public enum MyEnum {
    TOTO("some value", 1);
    ZOZO("some other value", 2);
}
```

And what I want to do is a getter like :

```
public static MyEnum getByName(String str) {
    [...]
}
```

So I can do :

```
MyEnum foo = MyEnum.getByName("TOTO");
MyEnum bar = MyEnum.getByName("ZOZO");
```

Comment: Use the built-in `MyEnum.valueOf(name)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Java enum has method `valueOf(String name)` which returns enum by name.

```
MyEnum foo = MyEnum.valueOf("TOTO");
MyEnum bar = MyEnum.valueOf("ZOZO");
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Okay I misunderstood the javadoc... But in this case wouldn't it be better to use `MyEnum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, "TOTO")` ?

Comment: @Dynamite There is no reason for that. Trust me :)

Comment: @Dynamite that would only be useful if the first parameter were only known at runtime, e.g. you've just got a variable `Class<? extends Enum<?>> someClass`.